# How to install Odoo server with all packages through alpine

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I need to install Odoo Server through alpine.

Odoo ubuntu installation commands are not working in the alpine.

Comment: This sounds more like something that belongs to [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). Also, please add a proper description of the problem instead of "not working".

Answer (score -1):

[Odoo doesn't work in Alpine](https://github.com/Tecnativa/docker-odoo-base/issues/16).

Besides, instructions for Ubuntu will never work in Alpine. But since it's not gonna work anyway, I recommend you to change to a different distribution.

Comment: Can you print a report with that? AFAIK you'll hit https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/issues/2 and/or related issues.